# how to add remote slave to my master in buildbot?

Tags: buildbot

I am trying to add remote slave to my master. The master is behind firewall. how can one add the remote slave to this master. do I have to open a new port ? if yes will master.cfg file will have two port number ? c['slavePortnum'] = 9989

Can anyone please help me in this regard. My question might not be clear because I my self dont know much about how to do this. I couple of slave that are within the network of master so I dont have to worry about the firewall but now I have to add remote slave I am worried that the connection might not happen because of the fire wall.

Comment: Is there some problem with just following the doc - http://docs.buildbot.net/current/tutorial/firstrun.html#creating-a-slave ?

Comment: Thank you yaccz for the comment . I agree Doc is clear about creating new slave for the master listening to the same port. What if I want two port on the same master? One port for slave that are on local network and other slave on remote.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: our university has strict internet policy so it wont let listen to same port for local and remote machine at same time. Our IT guy said that for remote connection I need different port. I personally am not sure whether it make sense or not :(

Comment: It doesn't. I think you would be better off figuring out how to get the hosts outside into the network. Like vpn or ssh tunneling and then  using the same port.

Comment: ok that sound plausible .. I will try this and let you know what happened .. thank you for the response though :)

Comment: also buildbot is using twisteds Perspective Broker. It could be trivial to write a PB proxy